# Download url in to directory

Tags: java, nio, apache-commons, apache-commons-httpclient

I need a download a text/plain file in to a folder. The url does not end with .txt but it has content-type etc... properly set. When I use the browser it immediately prompts me to save the file. The browser automatically puts proper file name also.

Using java how can i download that url in to a folder? Note that I dont know the filename also but I want the file to be saved in a directory.

**code to download a file is easy... my question is that I dont know by what name should i save my file. the filename is part of content-disposition header, now how do i extract that?**

Comment: The filename will be part of the HTTP Content-Disposition header in the response.

Comment: Hi anony, it's harder to help you figure out the problem
without concrete data and questions on Stack Overflow should solve a specific issue. Help us help you, by sharing the code you're using right now, possibly some sample data and any possible errors you encounter.
Adapt your question to include those and you'll surely get a helpful answer. Thanks for considering. :)

Comment: code to download a file is easy... my question is that I dont know by what name should i save my file. the filename is part of content-disposition header, now how do i extract that?

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP protocol uses the HTTP headers to define some information about the data transferred.

You have the `content-disposition` header that can have a property `filename` that is generated by the server. This holds the name of the file being transferred. But it is optional. Should you handle the case it is not present. Here is the doc: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html

Depending on how you download the file, you'll have dozen of ways to retrieve this file name from the http header.

Give a look to the apache http client for instance.

HIH
M.